# operations in the conditional expectation-$\int_DE(Y|\mathcal{D})(w)dP(w)$

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, conditional-expectation

[image]

---

[image]

For the first equation, I can see it can be rewritten as $$\int_DE(Y|\mathcal{D})(w)dP(w)=\int_\Omega Y(w)\mathbf{1_D}dP(w)\\
E(Y|D)P(D)=E(Y\mathbf{1_D})$$

and the second equation goes like $$P(A\cap D)=\int_DP(A|\mathcal{D})dP=\int_{\Omega}P(A|\mathcal{D})\mathbf{1_D}dP=P(A|D)P(D)$$

My first question goes like why those integral wrt $P$ seem to have no effect on those conditional functions. Then I convinced myself that $E(Y|\mathcal{D})\to E(Y|D)$ is the operation, if such argument valid, is the following operation make any sense?$$\int_{D}E(Y|D)dP$$  If it is, then how come having no effect under integral with respect to $P$

---

**self-updating as online storage**

finally figured out the consistency of these operations

$$\int_DE(Y|\mathcal{D})(w)dP(w)=\int_\Omega Y(w)\mathbf{1_D}dP(w)\\
\int_DE(Y|\mathcal{D})(w)dP(w)=E\{E(Y|\mathcal{D})\mathbf{1_D}\}=E\{E(Y\mathbf{1_D}|\mathcal{D})\}=E(Y\mathbf{1_D})=\int_\Omega Y(w)\mathbf{1_D}dP(w)$$

---

$$P(A\cap D)=\int_DP(A|\mathcal{D})dP=\int_{\Omega}P(A|\mathcal{D})\mathbf{1_D}dP=E\{P(A|D)\mathbf{1_D}\}=P(A|D)E\{\mathbf{1_D}\}=P(A|D)P(D)$$

Comment: $E(Y|D)$ doesn't make sense as the conditional expectation is respect to a $\sigma $-algebra and $D$ is just a set

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for your reply. Then what the integrate $E(Y|\mathcal{D})$ w.r.t $P$ exactly is. I meant in contrast to the idea that integrating an r.v with respect to $P$ is the expectation, what is integrating an expectation w.r.t $P$

Comment: a conditional expectation, intuitively, is a downgrade of a r.v. to a sub $\sigma $-algebra, this is what (1) exactly shows and the definition of the conditional expectation. The notion of conditional expectation is essential in martingales, one of the most useful kind of stochastic processes. Other way to see the conditional expectation is like a loss of information, that is, $Y$ is more informative than $E(Y|\mathcal{D})$ because $Y$ "lives" in a bigger $\sigma $-algebra

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for your reply. I was trying to convince myself that integrand $E(Y|\mathcal{D})$ should have some kind of "transformation". For example, $\int_\Omega YdP$ is the expectation of $Y$, integrand $Y$ becomes $E(Y)$ after integration. Take that idea into thise case:$$\int_D E(Y|\mathcal{D})dP=\int_{\Omega}E(Y|\mathcal{D})\mathbf{1_D}dP=E(Y|D)P(D)$$. $\mathbf{1_D}$ w.r.t $P$ becomes $P(D)$, this make sense, and $E(Y|\mathcal{D})$ w.r.t $P$ seems having no effect, it only takes the input $D,\,D\in\mathcal{D}$, make it realised. Cannot have a similar integral intuition.